# How to update my bios in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, bios, updates

I have this BIOS no

> INTEL MQ96510J.86A.0816.2006.0716.2308

Can anyone please tell me where I can find the update bios image and how can I update that. I don't have any floppy drive on my computer.

Comment: You cannot update a BIOS from directly within the OS. It has to be done with an external drive of some sort. You might be able to use a USB flash drive or a CD drive, but without more information, i could not tell you with any certainty if it is possible.

Comment: usually wherever you got the bios (mobo manufacturer website) will have the utilities and instructions for applying the bios right there too. What is the mobo model?

Comment: @Oliver: The BIOS can be updated from within Windows, if the manufacturer of the board or PC provides a utility to do so. That is how we update the BIOS on our HPs at work.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit of a lack of research here, and a certain lack of information - since i managed to google up an answer within a few minutes, but some specifics are lacking.

Firstly, there's a whole class of motherboards that use this chipset, and bios - unfortunately i cannot direct link - but go [here](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-010639.htm) and search for MQ96510J.86A, you will find the utility to update your bios from windows and alternate bios recovery utilities. Pick the one for your specific motherboard (though i suspect they're all the same download) and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of your BIOS is [1761](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&DwnldID=17520). That page has links to the BIOS file as well as a DOS and Windows update tools. You can use the Windows program to flash the BIOS, but even if there were only a DOS verison, you could still use that by making a bootable, DOS flash drive and setting your BIOS to boot from that.